# i18n messages: precedence of messages from multiple PO files

Tags: internationalization, plone, zope, buildout

I have created a schemaextender package, in which I am attempting to override certain strings for the `bika` and `plone` domains.  The source for my new package is here:  https://github.com/rockfruit/bika.uw.git

The installation method I recommend and use (for all plone addons/instances) is this:

- Install Plone's UnifiedInstaller.
- modify the 'eggs=' and 'develop=' lines, to include "bika.lims" and "bika.uw".
- run bin/buildout

With this installation method, my overrides are not overriding.  In zope.i18n I see that translationdomain.py always prefers the original translations, and only uses those from the schemaextender package when there is no identical string in the original `bika` catalog (ie, for messages translated in the Python or TAL code of the extension package itself; in all of the Bika or Plone code, my new catalogs are ignored).

I have read that the zcml= section in buildout.cfg may be used to force zcml load order to change, resulting in messages being preferred from earlier loaded packages.  So I have tried to modify as below, however the catalog from `bika.lims` is still preferred:

```
zcml =
    Products.CMFPlone
    bika.uw
    bika.lims
```

Now, here's a clue I found.  The github repository I linked to above has a buildout.cfg on the root, which does not use the UnifiedInstaller, but rather downloads Plone and other dependencies directly.  It contains no zcml= line.  But amazingly (to me) the translation overrides for both domains work (just like a bought one!) when using this installation method:

```
git clone https://github.com/rockfruit/bika.uw.git
cd bika.uw
virtualenv .
./bin/pip install zc.buildout
bin/buildout
bin/zeoserver fg &  # no idea why 'start' does not work
bin/zeoclient fg
```

My question is: What am I doing wrong, that the normal and recommended installation procedure prevents my translation overrides from taking their rightful precedence?

I'm embarrassed to admit, but I will anyway: This has baffled me for *years*.

I have pasted my existing buildout.cfg below, in which this morning I have attempted to mimic the behaviour of the bika.uw.git/buildout.cfg file, to no success.

---

```
[buildout]

# buildout-original.cfg is the Plone 4.3.4 zeocluster unified-installer file.
extends =
    buildout-original.cfg

zeo-address = 8081
client1-address = 8085
client2-address = 8086

effective-user = campbell
buildout-user = campbell
user=admin:adminsecret

need-sudo = no
var-dir=${buildout:directory}/var
backups-dir=${buildout:directory}/backups
deprecation-warnings = on
verbose-security = on

eggs =
    bika.uw
    bika.lims
    pudb
    i18ndude
    test
    robot
    zest.releaser

develop +=
    /home/campbell/Plone/repos/bika.uw
    /home/campbell/Plone/repos/bika.lims

parts =
    zeoserver
    client1
    client2
    backup
    zopepy
    unifiedinstaller

zcml =

[zeoserver]
<= zeoserver_base
recipe = plone.recipe.zeoserver
zeo-address = 127.0.0.1:${buildout:zeo-address}
zserver-threads = 1

[client1]
<= client_base
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
zeo-address = ${zeoserver:zeo-address}
http-address = ${buildout:client1-address}
resources = ${buildout:directory}/resources
locales = ${buildout:directory}/locales

[client2]
<= client_base
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
zeo-address = ${zeoserver:zeo-address}
http-address = ${buildout:client2-address}
resources = ${buildout:directory}/resources
locales = ${buildout:directory}/locales

[versions]
Cheetah = 2.2.1
plone.recipe.command = 1.1
plone.recipe.precompiler = 0.6
plone.recipe.unifiedinstaller = 4.3.1
Products.DocFinderTab = 1.0.5
ZopeSkel = 2.21.2
collective.recipe.backup = 2.14
zopeskel.dexterity = 1.5.3
zopeskekel.dexterity = 1.5.3
zopeskel.diazotheme = 1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the list I made for a [talk](https://github.com/mauritsvanrees/maurits.i18ntalk/blob/master/talk.rst#overriding-existing-translations) I gave at the Arnhem Plone conference in 2012 is still accurate. This is the order of loading of po files:

1. locales = ${buildout:directory}/locales
2. zcml = your.package
3. Products alphabetically until and including Products.CMFPlone
4. packages registered with z3c.autoinclude
5. rest of the Products
6. i18n folders (done by PlacelessTranslationService)

In your case: remove Products.CMFPlone from the zcml parameter.  It mixes up the order.